# Export Datatable parent and child data as excel in javascript

Tags: datatables, export-to-excel

I am trying to export jQuery data table as excel, data table is having both parent and child records. when I am using data table exports, its only exporting parent level records but not child.
how to export parent and child data in an excel. below is the table

```
date       price 
+ 6/July    30
+ 7/July    40
+ 10/July   50


  date      price 
- 6/July    30
   John     10
   Bobby    10
   Kevin     5
   Stella    5
+ 7/July    40
+ 10/July   50
```

export button is
Export All

and I am using the default functionality to export the data as excel.

```
$('#example').DataTable( {
    dom: 'Bfrtip',
    buttons: [
        'excel'
    ]
} );
```

Comment: Can you post what you've tried so far?

Comment: Hi @JechChua, I am using the default export functionality of data table. I have edited the question with that code.

Comment: I am assuming that you are using rowGroup.startRender to create "parent" and "child" rows. IF that is the case, then by default it will export all the data out as if nothing were grouped.